# Use a Batch File to list files and allow the user to select which file to pass to an executable

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-processing

I have a batch file that will display all files in a folder and allow the user to select a file by number and pass it to an executable. Everything works, however, I am trying to make this a click-and-forget type of batch file. In other words, I would also like the user to be able to select a number that would pass all files, one at a time, to said executable. My current code is as follows:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET index=1

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR %%f IN (*.txt) DO (
   SET file!index!=%%f
   ECHO !index! - %%f
   SET /A index=!index!+1
)

SETLOCAL DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET /P selection="select file by number:"

SET file%selection% >nul 2>&1

IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
   ECHO invalid number selected   
   EXIT /B 1
)

CALL :RESOLVE %%file%selection%%%

CSCRIPT //NoLogo //B C:\FCLoader\sendkeys.vbs

Z:\executable.exe %file_name%


GOTO :EOF

:RESOLVE
SET file_name=%1
GOTO :EOF
```

The CSCRIPT line is there to pass keystrokes from a vbs file to enter username, password, and a database name to the executable. This works fine. The executable works fine too if I just want to run it once against one file. Below is an example of what the batch looks like after running:

```
1 - file.txt
2 - file2.txt
3 - file3.txt
select file by number:
```

What I would like is for it to look like this:

```
1 - file.txt
2 - file2.txt
3 - file3.txt
4 - All
select file by number:
```

I would like for the user to be able to select 4 - All, and have it run the executable for every file, one at a time. When the first run through completes, it will call the executable again and so on...It will also need to run the vbs script before the executable is run in order for the credentials to be passed as stated above.

I have used the extent of my knowledge in Batch Files and now need help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET index=1
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR %%f IN (*.*) DO (
   SET file!index!=%%f
   ECHO !index! - %%f
   SET /A index=!index!+1
)
echo/!Index! - All
SETLOCAL DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET /P selection="select file by number: "
if "%selection%" equ "%index%" goto allFiles
SET file%selection% >nul 2>&1
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
   ECHO invalid number selected   
   EXIT /B 1
)
CALL :RESOLVE %%file%selection%%%
CSCRIPT //NoLogo //B C:\FCLoader\sendkeys.vbs
Z:\executable.exe "%file_name%"
GOTO :EOF
:RESOLVE
SET file_name=%1
GOTO :EOF
:allFiles
FOR %%f IN (*.txt) DO (  
   CSCRIPT //NoLogo //B C:\FCLoader\sendkeys.vbs
   Z:\executable.exe "%%f"
)
goto :EOF
```

Comment: I will try this on Monday when I get back to work, it looks good though. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Pick a file from a numbered list 1 to [a lot]!

This uses the choice command if less than 10 files (max files > 9999?? untested)

Files are numbered starting at 1 (not 0) - so 1-9.

Choice has timeout and default - but if more than 9 files no timeout
If more than 9 files and user presses ENTER key it uses the default value

Files are listed in date/time order - most recent first

A path and wildcard filter (* or ?) can be set for the dir command.
It could be adapted to run ALL as requested?

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
mode con: cols=185 lines=90
COLOR 1F

set MYPATH="G:\Downloads\*.iso"
set DEFAULT=1
set TIMEOUT=3

:GETISO
echo.
echo ISO FILES IN %MYPATH%
echo.
set count=1
set choose=
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('dir %MYPATH% /b/a-d/od/t:c') do (echo !count! %%i & set choose=!choose!!count!& set /A count=!count!+1)
echo.
set /a count=%count%-1
if %count%==0 echo NO FILES FOUND! & goto :EOF

if %count% LSS 10 CHOICE /C "%choose%" /N /M "SELECT DESIRED ISO (1-%count%) : " /T %TIMEOUT% /D %DEFAULT%
if %count% LSS 10 set /A ask=%errorlevel%+0

if %count% GEQ 10 (
set ask=%DEFAULT%
set /P ask="SELECT DESIRED ISO (1-%count%) : "
set /A ask=%ask+0
)

if "%ask%"=="" echo INPUT ERROR! & goto :GETISO
if "%ask%"=="0" echo INPUT ERROR! & goto :GETISO
if %ask% GTR %count% echo ERROR - NUMBER TO BIG! & goto :GETISO

set count=1
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('dir %MYPATH% /b/a-d/od/t:c') do (
if !count!==%ask% set FILE=%%i
set /A count=!count!+1
)

echo.
echo FILE=%ask% %FILE%
```